# Loop returning Message depending on how many characters you type

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

How come the loop is returning the message Enter # when done MORE instead of once depending on how many words you enter? EG type a single letter it loops the message Enter # when done but if you type what? it returns it Enter # when done x4 ....the same amount of letter in the word.I am new to c++ coming from c so im confused.Dont worry about other stuff in the code I need help with this. Thank you :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char sup;
  while (sup != '#') {
    std::cout << "Hi\n";
    std::cout << "Enter # when done";
    std::cin >> sup;
    if(sup == '#') {
      std::cout << "Ok you want to go.";
    }
  }
  std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: The code does exactly what you told it to do, however you might want to replace char, with std::string and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

As you set in while loop that `(sup != '#')`, it will take input character until you type `#`.

Comment: Yeah it was intented to my friend.but I still dont understand why it repeated the message more times the more letters i typed in the input.

Answer (score 0):

Example with std::string

```
// preferably do not include stdio.h in C++ programs
#include <string> 
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string input;  // use standard library string class

    while (input != "#")
    {
        std::cout << "Hi\n";
        std::cout << "Enter # when done : ";
        
        std::cin >> input;
        if (input == "#")
        {
            std::cout << "Ok you want to go.\n";
        }
    }

    return 0; // <== important to otherwise your program is ill-formed
}
```

Comment: I would suggest a further improvement is to loop with `while (true) { ... }`, with `input` locally scoped to the loop.

Comment: @Crhis Yeah that's fine too :)  Just wanted to change one thing at a time and teach std::string (too often I see that "C" style strings keep being used in C++)

Comment: Thank you It makes perfect sense.Both of you.More like this? I cant make it stop without a break tho. I added it to the bottom of the original post.

Comment: You could also make your loop a do...while loop makes it a bit more readable. You mean you do the extra cin.get to pause the program? Might be the ide you are using is closing the app for you after it has run, either run from the console directly, add a breakpoint or find the option in your ide that disables the auto close.
And sure if you have more questions just ask.

Comment: Ok added that to the code too.Works best so far I think.Thanks all Happy Holidays.